# Sum of series (n/1) + (n/2) + (n/3) + (n/4) +…….+ (n/n)

Tags: algorithms, summation

I wonder if there is a formula to calculate the sum of n/1 + n/2 + n/3 + n/4 + ... + 1. (Integer division)

The number `n` can be as large as 10^12, so a formula or a solution having the time complexity of O(logn) will work.

This is how far I can get:

1. The sum can be described as n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ... + 1/n). The series inside the parenthese is the Harmonic Progression which has no formula to calculate. So I don't think this can lead to a solution.
2. Playing with some numbers, this is what I get:

```
11 + 5 + 3 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
10 + 5 + 3 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
9 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
8 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
7 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
6 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1
5 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1
4 + 2 + 1 + 1
3 + 1 + 1
2 + 1
1
```

So by skipping the number 1s, we can reduce the time by a half. If using a loop to calculate the sum, we only need to loop until n/2. Since the rest contains only number 1s.

I've been trying to come up with a formula to calculate the series that is not 1 + 1 + ... + 1.
Please help if you know the acceptable answer (a formula or a O(logn) solution).

Comment: Hold up; are you talking about integer division or normal division?

Comment: Relevant link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487401/sum-of-floor-of-harmonic-progression-sum-i-1n-lfloor-frac-ni-rfloor-2-sum

Comment: @plshelp it's integer division

Comment: @eru-cs thanks, but I need to know how to come up with the second formula, which only needs to loop until sqrt of n.

Comment: @eru-cs please keep your answer, it's the one that I'm looking for. But I need the proof for that one to understand the solution. Otherwise it's just copy-paste stuff.

Comment: I deleted it when I saw you explicitly wanted a log-time solution, but sure I'll keep it up.

Comment: @plshelp thank you, but honestly I don't see the relation between the prime numbers and the sum, please post the explanation if possible.

Comment: Sorry I'll delete my post - mixed something up in my mind. But notice that your sum corresponds to the [divisor summatory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function) $D(n)$

Comment: "the Harmonic Progression which has no formula to calculate" -- this is wrong, see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicSeries.html

Answer (score 7):

Based on the following observation, you can derive a $O(\sqrt{n})$ time algorithm ( by computing the sum on the right-hand side naively in a $O(\sqrt{n})$-sized loop): (For $n=10^{12}$ this yields $n=10^{6}$ which is enough for say competitive programming sites which usually allow ~10^8 operations)

> For any positive integer $n$, Let $k=\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$:
> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor = 2\sum_{i=1}^k  \left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor - k^2
> $$

---

[This post on Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487401/sum-of-floor-of-harmonic-progression-sum-i-1n-lfloor-frac-ni-rfloor-2-sum) provides a clear visual proof of the equality above.

The following is a proof for the equality above that does not depend on a graph.

All variables below stand for positive integers. Let us fix $n$ and $k=\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$. For all $i, j\le n$, let
$\delta(i,j)=1$ if $i\cdot j\le n$. $\delta(i,j)=0$ otherwise. In particular,

- $\delta(i,j) = 1$ if $i,j\le k$.
- $\delta(i,j) = 0$ if $i,j\ge k+1$.

**Proposition**. $\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{i}\right\rfloor = \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n \delta(i,j) $ for all $i$.
Proof. Both sides count the number of positive multiples of $i$ that are smaller than or equal to $n$. $\ \checkmark$

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor 
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor 
 + \sum_{i=k+1}^n \left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor 
 + \sum_{i=k+1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \delta(i,j)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor 
 + \sum_{i=k+1}^n \sum_{j=1}^k \delta(i,j)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor 
 + \sum_{j=1}^k \sum_{i=k+1}^n \delta(i,j)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor 
 + \sum_{j=1}^k\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \delta(i,j)-\sum_{i=1}^k \delta(i,j)\right)\\
&= 2\sum_{i=1}^k \left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor 
 - \sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i=1}^k \delta(i,j))\\
&= 2\sum_{i=1}^k \left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor 
 - k^2 \quad \checkmark \\
\end{aligned}$$

The proof above is, basically, a direct translation of the visual proof.

Answer (score 0):

Following what eru-cs wrote you get a nice and fast formula, but it is mathematically quite difficult. If you are not that good at maths (and it is hard) and can afford a bit more execution time:

If k < $n^{1/2}$ then you can calculate easily the smallest and largest i such that n/i = k using integer division, and from that you can count how many such i there are; multiply by k and you get the sum of n/i for all these i.

You add up these sums, then you find for which i you didn’t add n/i and you add those. Done.

You can optimise this a bit, because the largest i such that n/i = k is one less than the smallest i such that n/i = k+1. And since calculating these sums is more complex, you might do the sums for $k < (n/2)^{1/2}$ for example.